# How can I use icon fonts in my photoshop projects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, web-fonts

I've been found a really good icon pack that is distributed for free like font awesome. I want to use that icons in my project but I can't find a way.
I have some .ttf and .svg files but I have no cheatsheet where copy/paste the glyph I need.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what your question is, but in photoshop there's a handy dandy "glyphs" panel that shows you all the characters available in a selected font (if the "icons" you're talking about are part of a font file). Type > Panels > Glyphs Panel

Answer (score 2):

There area couple of plugins you can use to make using Font Awesome (or other icon fonts) easier within photoshop:

[IconStack](http://missingpixels.io/plugins/iconstack/) lets you insert icons from several libraries in one click and then lets developers copy the html for that icon.

[FontAwesomePs](http://creativedo.co/FontAwesomePS) is simpler, just lets you drag FA icons into your PS document